# How to use ES6, AMD and CJS modules together with JSPM and system js?

Tags: javascript, amd, commonjs, jspm, es6-module-loader

I am trying JSPM, and consequently system JS, because I feel there is a lot of value in using ES6 features such as modules in my applications. However, I want to be able to manage my modules using CJS and AMD at the same time. Here is an example of the code in my main app file where I'm trying to load and run a CJS module and an ES6 one:

```
//CJS
var cjsmodule = require('./modules/cjs-module');
var cjs = cjsmodule();
cjs.init();

//ES6
import { square } from './modules/es6-module';
console.log(square(11));
```

but i get the error

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] TypeError: require is not a function
```

If I use just one approach, the application runs without errors. Does anyone know if it is possible to have ES6, CJS and AMD live together in the same application using JSPM?

Failing that, can anyone recommend an alternative module loader library that does support all three approaches simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I found it while trying to figure out how to use a couple of packages of different module styles. Hopefully this answer will save someone time.

JSPM can handle packages in a variety of formats: CommonJS, AMD, ECMA2016 modules, and global. When you install your package you can specify an override to tell JSPM how to load your package, e.g. `jspm install npm:your-mad-package-name-here -o "{format: 'cjs|amd|esm|global'}"` where the value in single quotes corresponds to the dependency type of the package. Using types exposed by the package is then simply a matter of importing them, `import typeNameHere from "your-amd-package-name-here";` where typeNameHere corresponds to the default or exported type(s). (There can be a little bit a learning curve around what to import depending the module type, what's exposed, and what you're wanting to use.)